# Combine XSD-descriptions

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc

How could I combine two XSDs to one? I want to use xjc to generate Java classes from the final XSD.

The two XSDs I have: 
http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd 
http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1/cache.xsd

An exisiting XML document using a combination of both: 
http://www.cachewiki.de/wiki/GPX#Geocaching.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import one schmema in definition of another:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
  xmlns:groundspeak="http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1/cache.xsd"
  targetNamespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:import schemaLocation="cache.xsd"  
     namespace="http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1/cache.xsd" />

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your one xsd schema in to other.